# Is there any fast way to create multiple copies of the same image with a different number on every single image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, batch-processing, numbering

I have to create a lottery "ticket" design and generate 1000 print cards with a different number on every single picture. Is there any quick way of doing that using Photoshop?

Comment: Which program are you using? InDesign?

Comment: I am using Photoshop

Comment: Try this: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-data-driven-graphics.html#define_variables it's not something I've tried in Photoshop. I could do a quick Step by Step in InDesign :(